# Instagram realtime subsrciption sends empty POST requests

Tags: php, json, instagram

I have a problem that Instagram send me empty data on real time subscription. Here is my steps

I am registering subscription

```
root@132701-10002:/var/www/realtime# curl -F 'client_id=MYSECRET'      -F 'client_secret= MYSECRET'      -F 'object=tag'      -F 'aspect=media'      -F 'object_id=newyork'      -F 'callback_url=http://myurl/realtime'      https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/
```

instagram answers me

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    },
    "data": {
        "object": "tag",
        "object_id": "newyork",
        "aspect": "media",
        "callback_url": "http://myurl/realtime",
        "type": "subscription",
        "id": "2838731"
    }
}
```

Its ok.

Than I am trying to accept instagram requests using this script:

```
<?php
if (@$_GET["hub_challenge"])
{
  echo $_GET["hub_challenge"];
}
$myString = file_get_contents('php://input');
$answer = json_decode($myString);
$ALL = date("F j, Y, g:i a")." ".print_r($answer,true)."\r\n";
file_put_contents('activity.log', $ALL, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

in activity constist from empty queries:

```
January 28, 2013, 12:09 pm 
January 28, 2013, 12:09 pm 
January 28, 2013, 12:09 pm 
January 28, 2013, 12:09 pm 
January 28, 2013, 12:09 pm 
January 28, 2013, 12:09 pm 
January 28, 2013, 12:09 pm 
January 28, 2013, 12:10 pm 
January 28, 2013, 12:10 pm 
January 28, 2013, 12:10 pm 
January 28, 2013, 12:10 pm 
January 28, 2013, 12:10 pm 
January 28, 2013, 12:10 pm 
January 28, 2013, 12:10 pm
```

Comment: is this right? ``(@$_GET["hub_challenge"])`` shouldnot it be ``($_GET["hub_challenge"])``?

Comment: changed to isset($_GET["hub_challenge"]) and it doesn't help

Comment: check for ``$myString = file_get_contents('php://input');`` with ``var_dump($myString);``, i think you are not being able to ``file_get_contents``

Comment: changed, it returns empty string in log: January 28, 2013, 12:58 pm string(0) ""

Comment: so it means, your url ``php://input`` isnot valid. is it your real url that you are using, or just posted here?

Comment: Try to simulate what Instagram will do to your URL. Try to CURL something into it in JSON and see what is happening.

Comment: yes, myurl - is just example, real url is: http://62.76.186.65/realtime/

Comment: I have catched: January 28, 2013, 1:10 pm string(37) "{"test": "hello from Stack Overflow"}"

Comment: 62.76.186.65/realtime redirects to 62.76.186.65/realtime/ I don’t know if Instagram supports 301 redirects. I had to manually post to 62.76.186.65/realtime/ to make it work. Try changing your callback url and add the trailing slash.

Comment: Thank you, it works! Instagram realy dosn't follow 301 redirects

Comment: @JérômeMahuet post it as an answer and OP should accept it

Comment: @VoldemarDuletskiy Post done :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to send a POST request to your callback URL, here is what I got:

```
curl -X POST x.x.x.x/realtime
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://x.x.x.x/realtime/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at x.x.x.x Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

I think Instagram does not support 301 redirects. So you may have to change your callback URL to add the trailing slash.

So your callback URL should be `http://x.x.x.x/realtime/`